# Getting rows given multiple values of a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that returns the following table (for example)

```
  ID      AVG        SIG     
 5X1PK  0.2712   0.004780167 
 DF5TB  39.4279  59.3092     
 5X1PK  64.8847  0.3614      
 DJII2  59.6743  26.7279     
 DRQUW  43.8942  0.2261      
 DRQUU  44.0606  0.128       
 DRQUW  43.6278  0.1562
```

I am able to get the rows for one value of a column using this formula

```
data2 <- data1[data1$ID == ('5X1PK'),]
```

Suppose, I want to get all rows for the ID's (5X1PK, DRQUW, DRQUU)  then the desired output that I want is

```
  ID      AVG        SIG     
 5X1PK  0.2712   0.004780167 
 5X1PK  64.8847  0.3614      
 DRQUW  43.8942  0.2261      
 DRQUU  44.0606  0.128       
 DRQUW  43.6278  0.1562
```

How do I get rows for multiple values of ID in one table?

Comment: Please put your data in a more friendly [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) format. Also, give an example of your desired output. It's unclear to me exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MrFlick  Thanks for pointing it out, I edited it to be more clear on the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `%in%`. For example,

```
data2 <- data1[data1$ID %in% c("5X1PK", "DRQUW", "DRQUU"), ]
data2
#      ID     AVG         SIG
# 1 5X1PK  0.2712 0.004780167
# 3 5X1PK 64.8847 0.361400000
# 5 DRQUW 43.8942 0.226100000
# 6 DRQUU 44.0606 0.128000000
# 7 DRQUW 43.6278 0.156200000
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works...

```
data2 <- data1[data1$ID == '5X1PK',]
```

To select multiple IDs you can add to the code as shown below:

```
data2 <- data1[data1$ID == '5X1PK' | data1$ID =='DF5TB',]
```