# Subsetting several different from a categorical variable in R

Tags: r, subset

I have an assignment where I need to use the subset() function on the iris dataset in R. Specifically, I have to work with only two of the three Species variables, setosa, virginica, versicolor.
Somehow, I cant get the subset function to pick more than one of these if I attempt to make a new dataframe where I only have setosa and virginica. How do I subset more than one of a categorical variable?

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting rows given multiple values of a column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266006/getting-rows-given-multiple-values-of-a-column-in-r)

Comment: Yes, definitely a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `%in%` keyword:

```
library(datasets)
data(iris)
subset(iris, iris$Species %in% c("setosa", "versicolor"))
```

Comment: Thank you, that is perfect! I guess I didn't write it out the correct way. Really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a subset where you specify which species from the variable name "Species" you want

```
dfSetosaVirginica <- subset(iris , Species %in% c("setosa","virginica"))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! That was efficient, thanks again!